# How to use string field values as URL parameters in Django and verify their existence or serve 404?

Tags: python, django

I have

```
def manufacturer(request, manufacturer_title):
#try:
#    m = Manufacturer.objects.filter(title__iexact=manufacturer_title)
#except Manufacturer.DoesNotExist:
#    raise Http404("No such manufacturer")
return HttpResponse("Manufacturer: %s" % manufacturer_title)
#return HttpResponse("Manufacturer: %s" % m.title)
```

You can see what I'm trying to do here. With only that second to last line not commented out, this works for any value entered for manufacturer_title, and prints it however it's typed, no matter whether it's valid or not. However clearly I need it to match an existing manufacturer. If I un-comment the above commented lines (excluding the last) the server is unable to connect.

Comment: What is the exact error that happens when you uncomment and connect?

Answer (score 0):

Django `filter` does not raise DoesNotExists error.
You can rewrite your code to this:

```
def manufacturer(request, manufacturer_title):
    m = Manufacturer.objects.filter(title__iexact=manufacturer_title)
    if not m.exists():
        raise Http404("No such manufacturer")
    return HttpResponse("Manufacturer: %s" % manufacturer_title)
```

or if `title` is uqique field you can just use `get()`:

```
  try:
       m = Manufacturer.objects.get(title__iexact=manufacturer_title)
  except Manufacturer.DoesNotExist:
       raise Http404("No such manufacturer")
  return HttpResponse("Manufacturer: %s" % m.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

**filter** does not raise an exception. May be you are trying to get a unique object, It can be done with **get** like this:

```
  Manufacturer.objects.get(title__iexact=manufacturer_title)
```

Now **get** will raise an exception if the object does not exist.

What you require in your case can be done with a shortcut function too. Like this:
If you require a single object:

```
 from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

 def manufacturer(request, manufacturer_title):
      m = get_object_or_404(Manufacturer, title__iexact=manufacturer_title)
      return HttpResponse("Manufacturer: %s" % manufacturer_title)
```

If you require a queryset:

```
   from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404

   def manufacturer(request, manufacturer_title):
      m = get_list_or_404(Manufacturer, title__contains=manufacturer_title)
      return HttpResponse("Manufacturer: %s" % manufacturer_title)
```